# How to know the origin url in cherrypy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

How do you get the baseurl in cherrypy? I see a cherrypy.url() which gives me the entire url "http://mywebaddress.com/currentpage"

Is there some similar function in cherrypy that allows me to just get the "http://mywebaddress.com"/"http://mywebaddress.com/" part regardless of the route I am on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). This will let you parse the URL into its components.

Answer (score 4):

The cherrypy.request object has [base](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.base) and [script_name](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.script_name) attributes.